# Do particle accelerators have to adjust for the sun's gravity due to length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, accelerator-physics

I believe particle accelerators move atoms at 99.999% the speed of light.  If the accelerator was oriented perpendicular to the sun, a particle moving at this speed would experience sizable length contraction in the direction of the sun. I calculated the normal gravitational acceleration of the sun at the radius of earth's orbit is 0.005 m/s2.  At 99% the speed of light the length contraction is 1/7 (the effective radius is 1/7 the radius of our frame of reference).  At 99.9% the contraction is contraction is 1/22 and when the earth's orbital radius is adjusted by this factor the gravitational acceleration is 0.27 m/s2.

There would be no such increase in the gravity experienced from the earth since the accelerator is parallel to the earth's surface.

At 99.99% the acceleration is 2.6 m/s2 and at 99.999% we have 26.8 m/s2, which is 2.6 times earth's gravity at the surface.

My question is do the operators of CERN, etc., have to account for these effects?  Have they been able to measure them?  I am thinking that even though the force is stonger than the earth's gravity the particle is moving too fast for the force to have any noticeable effect.  Also, the circular motion of these accelerators would make it difficult to detect and wold tend to cause the effect to cancel out, but it still might be possible to detect slowing/speed up on one axis.

Also, I know there have been linear accelerators.  Did length contraction and the sun's gravity have any measurable impact on these accelerators?

If this is not a concern or measurable effect I would be curious why.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you are getting the idea that length contraction means a larger acceleration from gravity, but it doesn't really matter anyway. The magnetic force on a single proton in the LHC, which has a field strength of $8.33~\rm T$ is about $4\times 10^{-10}~\rm N$. Comparatively the force of gravity of the earth on the same proton is around $1.6\times 10^{-26}~\rm N$, and the force of the sun's gravity is even less. Either way, gravitational force is utterly negligible to a relativistic particle in a particle accelerator.

Interestingly, the gravitational force of the sun and moon on the accelerator itself is much more important. The changing force of gravity on the accelerator causes its length and shape to shift ever so slightly with the tides, and this forces the LHC operators to re-tune the machine as the tides change. You can read more about that [here](https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2012/06/07/is-the-moon-full-just-ask-the-lhc-operators/).

Comment: The 'force' of gravity is dependent on the radius (or distance to the sun).  A Lorentz contraction in the direction of motion, when pointing to the sun, would reduce that distance and therefore increase the strength of the gravity.  When you are at 99.99X% of C the gravity of the sun becomes stronger than that of earth, and it can be and order of magnitude stronger or more.  But you did answer question by showing field strength dwarfs gravitation...

Comment: @RiverModel Okay, I see why you think that now. But that would be the force as measured in the proton's frame (and in that frame the sun would be moving at relativistic speeds, so there are additional corrections needed). In the lab frame, where we are making measurements, the sun is not any closer to the proton, so there is no such effect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the effect of Lorentz transformations on forces and acceleration (see [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity)), for example).

If we, the experimenters, are performing measurements from the lab frame on Earth, then the force exerted by the Sun on the particles would not be affected by this large [Lorentz $\gamma$ factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor). Only if we consider a reference frame, which is boosted at high velocity with respect to the Sun, would we observe such high values of the acceleration due to the Sun's gravitational force.

I assume experimentalists would not need to take into account such a small effect.

Comment: Correct. Now, the effect of Earth's magnetic field on fast charged particles is another question...

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, but that is a force that is already very large even without taking into account any changes of reference frame, which is what I think OP is asking about.

Comment: @JonCuster The earth's magnetic field is much, much smaller than the magnetic fields present in a typical accelerator, so even those are largely negligible. Though of course still much larger than the force of gravity.

Comment: @Chris - for the MeV ion range, the difference between pointing a beam line north vs east has a measurable difference in the beam simulations (order cm over a 10 m beamline). Sure, you just adjust the magnets a bit to mostly compensate, but long straight sections without steering magnets would be a problem.

Comment: @JonCuster Of course it's not negligible when there are no other magnets involved. But it's pretty atypical of an accelerator to have long straight stretches without bending magnets, focusing magnets, radiocavities, etc.